# create a read-only IAM user in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS. I tried to create a read-only IAM user in AWS console. I am not able to find the right permission. What permission I should grant? Please advise.

Answer (score 15):

There is an IAM Policy called `ReadOnlyAccess` that will (mostly) grant read-only access to all services. (I say 'mostly' because people might have different concepts of what is *read-only*.)

Individual services also have their own policies, such as `CloudSearchReadOnlyAccess` and `AmazonPollyReadOnlyAccess`.

To grant a user these permissions:

- Open the user in the IAM console
- Click **Add Permissions**
- Click **Attach existing policies directly**
- Select the desired policy
- Save the permissions

Comment: I do not see ReadOnlyAccess policy in the list. :(

Comment: It's there, believe me! To find it: Click on **Policies**, search for `readonly`, then sort the Policy Name column _backwards_. You'll find it near the top of the list (because it's near the end alphabetically).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. When I search for "ReadOnlyAccess" I expect the exact match (if available) to be the first in the results. Am I expecting too much?

Comment: got it... it's on page 2... thanks!